# Clearing unused Microsoft Store WindowsApps folders

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, windows-store

TLDR: Trying to find how to delete the unwanted files from C:\Program Files\WindowsApps

I've got a Windows 10 machine that's used up all of its 118GB available space. Within Windows Explorer I tried to find which folder was using all the space, but even when checking the properties of all the folders on C:\ it still didn't come close to the drive's available space.

Using the TreeSize app I was able to determine that the WindowsApps folder contains loads of files/folders relating to apps that aren't actually installed (just ready to be installed), mostly games like CandyCrush, RoyalRevolt, MarchofEmpires etc, using over 40GB, with many having multiple versions of the same app. For instance RoyalRevolt has v9.0, v8.6, v8.5, v8.4, v8.0 etc, each using about 500MB.

[image]

Within the Microsoft Store I was able to uninstall some of them, but that had no impact on used space, and I've turned off "Update apps automatically" for now so that'll hopefully stop it getting any worse.

From an elevated PowerShell I was able to use :

Get-AppxPackage -allusers *candy*

to find some additional installations of the apps, but only a couple compared to the 10s of versions in the folder, and then use

Get-AppxPackage -allusers *candy* | Remove-AppxPackage -allusers

to remove those from the list, but the vast majority of those files remain (the two listed below are the only two that were returned, yet you can see in the TreeSize screenshot that there are loads of other folders for that app).

[image]

I've tried going into Settings > Apps > Microsoft Store > Advanced options > Reset, but that had no effect.

There's nothing showing as available to be removed from Disk Clean-up.

While TreeView shows those folder, and from an elevated PowerShell window I can access the WindowsApps folder (unlike with Explorer), if I attempt to delete the folders I'm perhaps unsurprisingly unable to and get a "Access to the path is denied" error.

Comment: You could try uninstalling with BCUninstaller: https://www.bcuninstaller.com/ It supports Windows Store apps, you'll need to temporarily install them back again I'm pretty sure, though. it can also get rid of other leftovers.

Comment: Sorted. The thread https://superuser.com/questions/1495993/how-can-i-free-up-space-taken-up-by-an-incomplete-microsoft-store-download and specifically the answer from @A_S00 fixed it.